# Refreshing UILabel on applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I am trying to refresh a label whenever the app comes back from a background state, however I cannot find a way to reference that label.

However, if I add label.text = titles[emotionOfTheDay] under applicationWillEnterForeground in the app's delegate, it will rightfully tell me it doesn't know what label I'm talking about, because the label is in my ViewController. Is there a way to reference this label from a different file or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit { 
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc fileprivate func willEnterForeground() {
    // refresh the label here 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'd have my VC listen for the change, good idea. But Xcode is complaining that: Use of unresolved identifier 'willEnterForeground' Changing it to 'applicationWillEnterForeground' doesn't help.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. https://www.dropbox.com/s/oa72swyqbz8b3b4/Screenshot%202018-06-11%2001.03.22.jpg?dl=0

Comment: you need to add the method in the selector copy whole answer

Comment: Ok, I see. It still suggested I change willEnterForeground to handleWillEnterForeground but it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why did you use deinit does deallocation handle by ARC? @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

This is my shorter version:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

To be implemented in for instance viewDidLoad()